# iPhone External Accessory showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I have connected my iPhone 5 with a lightning extender cable and USB camera adapter cable(MFI Approved) in this sequence( iPhone -> Extender cable -> USB camera adapter). I want to know the Connected and Disconnected status of the USB camera adapter. In the above arrangement my sample app shows USB camera adapter as connected but after removing the USB camera adapter it still shows connected to iPhone. Why is it so. Please help me.

Comment: Could you show your code? What do you mean by still connected? Did you listen to the connection and deconnection. If I remember well, it's notification that you should listen to.

Comment: Yes i am using these two notification methods i.e EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification,EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification. Here Still Connected means that when i am disconnecting the USB camera adapter from extender cable. It does not fire Disconnected notification. Even the connectedAccessories count does not change.